# Is it possible to connect to an i2c device through a USB to RS485 serial converter cable?

Tags: usb, serial

I currently have a sensor attached to a USB to RS485 Serial converter cable which is plugged in to a raspberry pi. I've tried using the ftdi d2xx drivers to connect to it, but so far I can't read any data and while the writes don't fail, I'm not sure they're working.

This setup works on Windows with the custom software provided by the manufacturer, but I can't find anything on getting it to work on a linux system. Is this possible?

Comment: ??? What do you mean by "this works on windows"? I very much doubt an I2C device operates on a RS485 bus, those two interfaces are quite different.

Comment: What device?  Why not connect it to the Pi's I2C bus?

Comment: So basically I have a Sensirion sensor connected to an RS485 USB to Serial converter cable which is plugged into the Pi. It works on Windows but Sensirion has an application that just works with this that isn't available on Linux. I can't access the pi directly (there's a case around it that I can't open) so I can only access it through the provided USB ports. Sorry for how vague this is, this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: I think you are better off asking Sensiron if they provide Linux drivers or know of another way of using the sensor from Linux.